# C# button pause

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, button, click

I am making a digital clock in a GUI on C#. I have 5 buttons, 4 for the time zone conversions, and one for close forms.

My question is, when I press button one (Central Time conversion from my system time) it will flash the time in the label box for about 1 second and revert back to my current system time.

In console I know there is a pause execution to pause the program. How can I use a pause to hold the central time button on that setting yet keep the timer running? I am open to using multiple forms.

Here is my code for the button:

```
private void Central_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hr = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    hr = DateTime.Now.Hour - 1;
    min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
    sec = DateTime.Now.Second;

    if (hr > 12)
        hr -= 12;

    if (sec % 2 == 0)
    {
        time.Text = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    }
    else
    {
        time.Text = hr + " " + min + " " + sec;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want your program to sleep for a few seconds to show your data and then continue the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, maybe something like this will work for you:

```
private void Central_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here you could disable all the buttons

    // endTime defines how long we will show this time zone (5 seconds)
    var endTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    while (DateTime.Now < endTime)
    {
        // Show the short time format (hh:mm:ss AM|PM)
        var displayText = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).ToString("T");

        if ((DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 1))
        {
            // Every other second, hide the colons
            displayText = displayText.Replace(":", " ");
        }

        time.Text = displayText;

        // Sleep for one second
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    // And here you can enable the buttons again
}
```

One other thing to note is that there are built-in methods for converting to another time zone. Basically, you get the UTC (universal) time, and then convert it to the time zone you're interested in. The code above could be converted to use this like so:

```
private void Central_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // endTime defines how long we will show this time zone (5 seconds)
    var endTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    while (DateTime.Now < endTime)
    {
        // Get UTC time
        DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Convert it to Central Time
        var displayText = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, 
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"))
            .ToString("T");

        if ((DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 1))
        {
            // Every other second, hide the colons
            displayText = displayText.Replace(":", " ");
        }

        time.Text = displayText;

        // Sleep for one second
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear. But I guess you are simply making a **regular clock**. For this all you need to do is to make the time zone settings **persist**. So you need to **store** them in a class level variable or two, maybe like this:

```
TimeSpan correction = new TimeSpan(0);
string zone = "ET";

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // display the corrected time with its name
    time.Text = (DateTime.Now + correction).ToString("h:mm:ss ") + zone;
}

private void Central_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    correction = new TimeSpan(-1, 0, 0);  // set the hours of the new zone
    zone = "CT";                         // set its name
}
```

I hope you have a nicer name for the Timer, like the other names you use.. (Although I always include a prefix that shows me the Type of the control..)

Please also have a look at the sleuth of predefined date and time formats, many of which will work according to your machines localization:

[Standard Date&Time patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Long time pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#ShortTime)

If I didn't understand what you mean by 'pausing', please clarify! If maybe you want not to really switch to a new timezone but only display its time for a short while, you just need to add 3 or 4 lines..:

A new variable to hold the time yet to hold the zone:

```
int secondsToHold = 0;
```

One line in the click to set it to a few seconds, here I cose 3 seconds:

```
secondsToHold = (int) (3 *  1000f /timer1.Interval);
```

And finally code in the Tick event to check and reset the varaibles:

```
if (secondsToHold > 0) secondsToHold -= 1;
else { correction = new TimeSpan(0); zone = "ET"; }
```